# Плавное изменение скорости воспроизведения видео Android

Tags: android, видео, videoview, android-asynctask

Хочу сделать приложение, в котором скорость видео будет постепенно замедляться, если пользователь не нажимает на кнопки. Изменять скорость видео при помощи кнопок получилось, используя библиотеку Exomedia. Но аналогично сделать это автоматическим с AsyncTask не получается: замедляет через раз, а картинку и вовсе останавливает намертво. Как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Media Player](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setPlaybackParams(android.media.PlaybackParams)) начиная с API 23 имеет метод [setPlaybackParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setPlaybackParams(android.media.PlaybackParams)). Я тестировал, у меня видео замедлялось.

Comment: При помощи этого метода получается изменить скорость до запуска видео, но менять ее постоянно, в процессе воспроизведения не получается.

Comment: Только, что протестировал: меняет скорость в процессе воспроизведения.

Comment: В цикле? Скинь код, пожалуйста. Хочу понять, что с моим не так.

Comment: Вообщем, сам уже реализовал через MediaPlayer, спасибо за наводку.